# Incorrect syntax near the keyword «JOIN»

Tags: java, sql-server, database, join, netbeans

Please, help me find the error. I checked it in the SqlServer and everything was good. But NetBeans giving the error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword" JOIN "»

```
String query = "SELECT Sale.date_sale, Cheque.quantity, Goods.price, Cheque.quantity*Goods.price" +
"FROM Sale JOIN Cheque ON Sale.id = Cheque.id_sale JOIN Goods ON Goods.id = Cheque.id_goods" +
"WHERE Sale.date_sale BETWEEN '2001-04-12' AND '2015-06-12' AND Goods.id = 1";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: post the full error to known which JOIN is causing the error and you should add space between every concatenation... like this: `"...Goods.price " + " FROM Sale..."` because without that the string is : `"...Goods.priceFROM Sale..."`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding spaces at the beginning or end of the strings you're concatenating:

```
String query = "SELECT Sale.date_sale, Cheque.quantity, Goods.price, Cheque.quantity*Goods.price" +
" FROM Sale JOIN Cheque ON Sale.id = Cheque.id_sale JOIN Goods ON Goods.id = Cheque.id_goods" +
" WHERE Sale.date_sale BETWEEN '2001-04-12' AND '2015-06-12' AND Goods.id = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert spaces at the beginning of the strings you're concatenating, or else you will wind up with bad expressions such as "Cheque.quantity*Goods.priceFROM" and "Cheque.id_goodsWHERE".